# How to reset a data model in realm?

Tags: objective-c, realm

I am using Realm to store data. I store response of a API in One data model of type RLMObject. After when i am hitting api again and storing in that data model.

I try to deleting all object of that data model before and after hitting api through query of all objects and realm delete objects. But my application got crash or not working as desire.

```
    RLMResults<ApprovalCards *> *approval = [ApprovalCards allObjects];
        RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealm defaultRealm].configuration;
        RLMRealm *aRealm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config
                                                      error:nil];

        [aRealm beginWriteTransaction];
        [aRealm deleteObjects:approval];
        [aRealm commitWriteTransaction];
```

I want the previous data to be removed and store only new response.

Comment: I think you should put in a check on if approval holds any objects and if you get any errors from realmWithConfiguration call. And since you have the privilege of transactions, why don't you insert the new data in there as well? In that way you won't have any time without no data. Finally, what error do you see in the crash?

Comment: I am inserting new data but the old one still persist. Now i solve the problem by removing all data by code before hitting api. thats was error of done on different thread. but i am wondering any other solution of that or any other ways.